# JS: Get Y Position of a String in Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Long story short, I want to create a very basic search in my Html div.
Each possible search tag starts and ends with `$`. Each tag is unique.

My goal is to create a function that takes a tag, search through the div, find the line (Y position) of that tag in the div.

Only problem is to get the line position of a string. I can find if the string is there, but I have no information about its position in the div.

(In the example, it is represented by `getLineWhereTagIsFound(tag)` ).

Note: I could possibly count the amount of `<br>` until I find the tag but I don't know how reliable it would be.

This is what I have so far.

```
    <div id="helpText" class='onlyTextScroll container'>        
        $Fruits$<br>
        Fruits are very nice.<br>
        Fruits are very nice.<br>
        Fruits are very nice.<br>
        Fruits are very nice.<br>
        Fruits are very nice.<br>
        Fruits are very nice.<br>
        Fruits are very nice.<br>
        Fruits are very nice.<br>
        <br>
        $Vegetables$<br>
        Vegetables are very evil.<br>
        Vegetables are very evil.<br>
        Vegetables are very evil.<br>
        Vegetables are very evil.<br>
        Vegetables are very evil.<br>
        Vegetables are very evil.<br>
        Vegetables are very evil.<br>
        <br>
    </div>


<script>
function updateHelp(tag){
    var y = getLineWhereTagIsFound('$' + tag + '$');
    y *= lineHeight;
    $("#helpText").scrollTop(y);

}
/* Example
function updateHelp('Vegetables'){
    var y = getLineWhereTagIsFound('$' + 'Vegetables' + '$');
    //y would be 10 because $Vegetables$ is found on line 10; 
    //let say lineHeight is 10;     
    y = y*lineHeight; //10*10

    $("#helpText").scrollTop(100);

}
*/
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, `<br>` counting is a bad idea because text can go to the next line even without a `<br>` if the windows width is smaller than the line's length

Comment: You're making this too hard. If you put the text in an element, like a `span` or a `p`, you can locate the element. Then use `element.scrollIntoView`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView

Comment: Actually, only the tags would need to be in an element, if I understand this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLineWhereTagIsFound(tag){
    var helpText = document.getElementById("helpText");
    var count = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<helpText.childNodes.length;i++){
        if(helpText.childNodes[i].nodeType==3){
            count++;
            if(helpText.childNodes[i].nodeValue.indexOf(tag)>=0){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
    //count would be 11,not 10, because $Vegetables$ is found on line 11
    //each <br/> one line
}
```